# OnClientClick doesnt work in Formview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, alert, formview

I am working in asp.net vb.net. I have a datagrid with a update button like this : 
`OnClientClick="return
            ('Succesfully updated!')">`
Which works like a charm.

And I have this one in the formview:

`OnClientClick="return
            ('Succesfully edited!')">`

Its exactly the same button as in the gridview, but it doesnt seem to work? Complete buttons:

```
      <asp:Button 
        ID="ButtonUpdate" 
        runat="server" 
        CssClass="details"
        CausesValidation="True" 
        CommandName="Update" 
        Text="Update"
        OnClientClick="return
        ('Succesfully updated')">
    </asp:Button>
```

The other one is exactly the same but with different text and a other ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are try to fire alert() function on client click 
try this:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonUpdate" runat="server" 
        CssClass="details"
        CausesValidation="True" 
        CommandName="Update" 
        Text="Update"
        OnClientClick="javascript:alert('Succesfully updated');"></asp:Button>
```

Comment: Weird but it worked, how come it does work on gridview but not in formview?

Anyway major thanks! I'll accept the awnser in 8 minutes :)

Comment: Thanks. Please vote this answer as Up if this solve your problem..:)

Comment: This should worked in formview also if you see your html code and it will creating a proper onclientclick function then it should worked...

Comment: Yes this works in formview, but mine dindt, but did in gridview, weird though

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question but a client click handler will be expecting a boolean result to determine if it should execute the post back.  You are returning a string value which won't do anything at all.

What are you expecting to occur?